# Why I cannot access kafka-rest (started in docker-container) from another container (it's runs Karate-tests) only in Gitlab pipeline?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, kafka-rest

I run my pipeline in image: `docker/compose:latest`.
I use this script to build and run containers in this image:

```
script:
    - docker-compose up -d
    - CONTAINER_ID=$(docker-compose ps -q karate)
    - EXIT_CODE=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.ExitCode}}' $CONTAINER_ID)
    - |
      if [ $EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Tests passed!"
      else
        echo "Tests failed with exit code: $EXIT_CODE"
        exit 1
      fi
```

And check exit code of my container with Karate tests.
Test have access to API (send request to `http://api:35000/`), and to Kafka-Rest (send request to http://kafkarest:38082), but only locally, if I run `docker-compose up -d` on my PC.

If I run pipeline via script above, I can just connect and send request from my tests to API (via http://api/assets-api/upload-photo), but when i send request to Kafka-Rest to `http://kafkarest:38082/consumers/testgroup`, I got error: `Connect to kafkarest:38082 [kafkarest/172.20.0.12] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), http call failed after 43 milliseconds for url: http://kafkarest:38082/consumers/testgroup`.
Also I tried to access http://kafkarest/, http://docker:38082, http://localhost, but it didn't help me. Which url I should use to connect to Kafka Rest?

My docker-compose:

```
api:
    container_name: 'api'
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "kafka"
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - 35000:80
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
    networks:
      - capy-network

  karate:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-karate
    environment:
      - KARATE_ENV=mr
    depends_on:
      - db
      - s3
      - api
      - kafkarest 
    networks:
      - capy-network

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.1
    container_name: 'zookeeper'
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports: 
    - "32181:32181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    networks:
      - capy-network

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.1
    container_name: 'kafka'
    hostname: kafka
    ports: 
    - "29092:29092"
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      - capy-network

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui
    container_name: 'kafka-ui'
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:29092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=zookeeper:32181
    links:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper 
    networks:
      - capy-network  

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:4.1.1
    container_name: 'schema-registry'
    hostname: schema-registry
    ports:
    - "38081:38081"
    depends_on:
    - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:32181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://schema-registry:38081
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG: "true"
    networks:
      - capy-network

  kafkarest:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:4.1.1
    container_name: 'kafkarest'
    hostname: kafkarest
    ports:
    - "38082:38082"
    depends_on:
      - schema-registry
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: schema-registry:38081
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: kafkarest
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://kafkarest:38082
    networks:
      - capy-network
```

Comment: KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS looks like it is setting up the listen rather than publish address for the kafka rest process. It should be http://0.0.0.0:38082 so that connections from any other address are accepted. As it is, if it is a listen address, the kafkarest service will only listen for connections from itself.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Okay, so, If i set this property, on which url I can access kafka-rest from my karate-tests?

Comment: that container would use the `http://karaterest:38082` url. I am not familiar with kafka to be sure, but it looks like anything that is "*_CONNECTION_URL" would use the other service name. Anything thats "*ADVERTIZED_LISTNERS" ... might need the actual service name too. But anything thats setting up an actual listener needs 0.0.0.0 so it can accept incomming requests. Im not sure of the conventions however.

Comment: Maybe you want say `http://kafkarest:38082`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I detected a problem. We need to restart container with tests or add a delay for it, because Kafka Rest need some time to "wake up". After 3 restarts I've got test results. Tests were passed.